# See actual HTML code of component instead of component selector

Tags: angular

When I create angular app, I see angular mark up (selector) in browser (view source).

app-root /app-root

Is it possible to see the mark up of app component instead of angular markup in browser?

Comment: Inspect Element in your browser will show you each DOM element

Comment: Is the app actually *running*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can see the actual code inside app.component.html, if you view source, you will see a bunch of javascript files appended to index.html, one of them is `main.bundle.js`, now this file contains the code you are looking for. You will be able to see code of `app.component.ts` etc..

[image]

As you can see in the above image, it shows the full code of `app.component.html` and if you scroll a little, you will also be able to see the content of `app.component.ts`.